# Using Promises - result not returning

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I have the following:

```
    resolutionTestBuilder.buildTests().then(function(tests) {
        var s = tests; // checking result
    });
```

`buildTests` looks like this:

```
resolutionTestBuilder.buildTests = function () {
    Promise.all([createAllResolutions(), deviceScanner.scanDevices()])
        .spread(function (resolutions, videoDevices) {
            var tests = [];
            resolutions.forEach(function (targetResolution) {
                videoDevices.forEach(function (videoDevice) {
                    tests.push({ device: videoDevice, resolution: targetResolution });
                });
            });
            return tests;
        });
}
```

`createAllResolutions` looks like this:

```
 var createAllResolutions = function () {
    for (let y = maxHeight; y >= minHeight; y--) {
       resolutions.push(
          {x:x,y:y}
       );
    }
    return resolutions;
}
```

And finally, `scanDevices` looks like this:

```
deviceScanner.scanDevices = function() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(availableDevices) {
        var videoDevices = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < availableDevices.length; ++i) {
            if (availableDevices[i].kind === 'videoinput') {
                videoDevices.push({ label: availableDevices[i].label || 'camera ' + (videoDevices.length + 1), id: availableDevices[i].deviceId });
            }
        }
        return videoDevices;
    });
}
```

The behavior that I'm seeing is that the `.spread` parameters are partially complete - I get `resolutions` but not `videoDevices`.  This is my first attempt at promises (and bluebird) so I'm probably missing something very fundamental here - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `resolutionTestBuilder.buildTests` doesn't return anything? neither does `deviceScanner.scanDevices`

Comment: @JaromandaX - I'm attempting to return `tests` here - I think I'm really messing up the flow though.  Should I return a promise?

Comment: `return Promise.all ....` and `return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then ...` etc may be the ticket ... just like any function, if you don't return anything, nothing gets returned (technically, `undefined` gets returned)

Comment: @JaromandaX that did it - thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return`ing from the `then` callbacks is not enough, you need to `return` the promise that the `then()` call creates from the function!

```
resolutionTestBuilder.buildTests = function () {
    return Promise.all([createAllResolutions(), deviceScanner.scanDevices()])
//  ^^^^^^
        .spread(function (resolutions, videoDevices) {
            …
        });
};
deviceScanner.scanDevices = function() {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(availableDevices) {
//  ^^^^^^
        …
    });
};
```